# mypy [subprocess.Popen] `Item "None" of "Optional[IO[bytes]]" has no attribute "close"`

Tags: popen, mypy

`mypy` generates following warning `Item "None" of "Optional[IO[bytes]]" has no attribute "close"` for the `p1.stdout.close()`line. How can I fix this error?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

filename = "filename.py"
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["ls", "-ln", filename,], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(["awk", "{print $1}"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # <== `Item "None" of "Optional[IO[bytes]]" has no 
                   #     attribute "close"`
```

---

`close()` is an `abstractmethod()` method in the `typing.py` file

```
@abstractmethod
def close(self) -> None:
   pass
```

Comment: `if p1.stdout is not None: p1.stdout.close()`?

Comment: Aside from that, you can turn strict optional checking off by running `mypy --no-strict-optional`, or ignore the error by adding a trailing `# type: ignore` comment.